# Fit YouTube video thumbnail in UIWebView on video start up

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uiwebview

I'm loading Youtube video inside UIWebView using following code.

```
let videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9GujgK0y2M"
let embedHTML = "<iframe width=\(self.webView.frame.size.width)\" height=\(self.webView.frame.size.height)\" src=\(videoUrl)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

Starting thumbnail for video is very large. I need to fit it according to size of UIWebView. Please help me, How can I change it ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code can help you:

```
let yourVideoID = "F9GujgK0y2M"
let css = ".video-container {position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;} .video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; }"
let url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(yourVideoID)?playsinline=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&showsearch=0&loop=1&iv_load_policy=3"
let htmlString = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">\(css)</style></head><body><div class=\"video-container\"><iframe src=\"\(url)\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div></body></html>"

yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = false
yourWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
yourWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617950-scalespagetofit), setting this to `true` scales the webpage to fit the screen.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be greatly improved if it included an explanation of how it addresses the question. Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing the `height` and `width` properties in the `iframe` HTML tag made the frame fit the page width altogether.